# Fixing Windows Boot on UEFI with MBR partition

Tags: windows-10, boot, uefi, mbr, gpt

The laptop I currently own came with Windows 10 preinstalled. I installed Ubuntu 19.10 onto it (in dual boot). Back then I had no idea about MBR, GPT, BIOS, UEFI or any of that stuff, just followed the default instructions and "it worked".

Now recently I decided to shift to Manjaro, so I installed Manjaro replacing the Ubuntu parition. The installer told me that UEFI needs a EFI partition. So I decided to look into it. Turns out my SSD was formatted in MBR and I have a UEFI firmware. So I created a 512 MB FAT32 partition (as `/boot/efi/`). The installation was successful, and I have a working Manjaro installation. Just one issue, `sudo update grub` can't find Windows. I checked the Windows parition still exists. But since I created the new EFI parition it has no Microsoft folder (`/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft`). So I thought I was going to repair the efi bootloader of Windows, and then I came across that Windows can't handle UEFI on an MBR paritioned drive.

Source for some of the info I learned:
https://superuser.com/a/739285/1216782
[Booting with MBR in UEFI (No CSM mode at all)?](https://superuser.com/questions/1067709/booting-with-mbr-in-uefi-no-csm-mode-at-all)

So my question is how do I get my Windows to boot (fix it) without loosing data, if it's even possible. Do I have to convert MBR to GPT? If so how do I go about it considering my current situation?

Comment: MBR and UEFI are not compatible with one another with regards to Windows.  It’s impossible to boot Windows in UEFI without GPT.  If you have more than 3 partitions, you can’t use MBR2GPT which is a built-in tool.  Other tools typically cannot do this conversion without data loss

Comment: Perfect way already told by Ramhound. Other thing you can try is 'hybrid MBR': https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html : whole disk will be in gpt ; linux will too see disk as gpt (gdisk will show it as hybrid mbr) and windows will see the disk as mbr ; will add more details if want to try this(let me know). And lastly since you are new to this ,if data in drives are very important then don't follow this ! You may mess up the things !!!